# Phonegap android app h3 tag not allow font customising?

Tags: html, css

i am create a project in cordova 3.4 and set a custom font to h3, it working fn in ios devices and some android but some android devices (like 10" and above tablets) are not supporting the font I don't have any idea

```
@font-face{
    font-family: "arabic";
    src: url('../fonts/arabic.ttf')  format('truetype');
}


h3 {
font-family: arabic;
font-size: 22px;
padding-bottom: 0;
margin: 0;
line-height: 21px;
font-weight: 400;
color: black;
display: block;
color: #082F68;

}
```

Comment: Please show your CSS. Also, how are some Android devices different? What version of Android and WebKit are they running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> You don't use default style of h3,
>    Then why are you using this tag, 
>   I
>   think **** SPAN **** is better option in this time

Comment: Thanks for your valuable advice